# WSO2 Identity Server 4.1.0: User store is operating in read only mode. Cannot write into the user store

Tags: wso2, readonly, wso2-identity-server

I'm getting the following error when I start WSO2 Identity Server 4.1.0:

```
[2013-02-27 17:00:33,192] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.identity.mgt.IdentityMgtEventListener} -  Error while init identity listener
org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: User store is operating in read only mode. Cannot write into the user store.
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager.doSetUserClaimValue(ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager.java:1293)
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager.setUserClaimValue(AbstractUserStoreManager.java:823)
at org.wso2.carbon.identity.mgt.IdentityMgtEventListener.<init>(IdentityMgtEventListener.java:68)
at org.wso2.carbon.identity.mgt.internal.IdentityMgtServiceComponent.activate(IdentityMgtServiceComponent.java:89)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
...
```

That means that WSO2 is trying to write in the ldap, but i've configured it to be read only:

```
<UserStoreManager class="org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager">
    <Property name="ReadOnly">true</Property>
    <Property name="MaxUserNameListLength">100</Property>
    <Property name="ConnectionURL">ldaps://xxxx:636</Property>
    <Property name="ConnectionName">uid=xxx,ou=xx,dc=xx,dc=xx,dc=x</Property>
    <Property name="ConnectionPassword">xxxxxx</Property>
    <Property name="passwordHashMethod">SHA</Property>
    <Property name="UserSearchBase">ou=xx,dc=x,dc=xx,dc=xx</Property>
    <Property name="UserNameListFilter">(objectClass=person)</Property>
    <Property name="UserNameAttribute">uid</Property>
    <Property name="ReadLDAPGroups">true</Property>
    <Property name="GroupSearchBase">ou=xx,dc=xx,dc=xx,dc=xx</Property>
    <Property name="GroupNameListFilter">(objectClass=posixGroup)</Property>
    <Property name="GroupNameAttribute">cn</Property>
    <Property name="MembershipAttribute">memberUid</Property>
    <Property name="UserRolesCacheEnabled">true</Property>
    <Property name="ReplaceEscapeCharactersAtUserLogin">true</Property>
    <Property name="maxFailedLoginAttempt">0</Property> 
</UserStoreManager>
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: I'm seeing the same issue.  Here's my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15392148/wso2-identity-server-ldap-user-store-not-working

Answer (score 1):

Your read-only user store should contain the 'admin' user, which is specified in the realm configuration section at the top of user-mgt.xml.

```
<AdminUser>
    <UserName>admin</UserName>
    <Password>admin</Password>
</AdminUser>
```

Since it could not be found, WSO2 IS is trying to write it.