# WSO2 Identity Server - LDAP user store not working

Tags: active-directory, wso2

I'm trying to configure the Identity Server (4.1.0) against our corporate Active Directory.

I am using the ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager class.  Here is the configuration for the user store:

```
<UserStoreManager class="org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager">
            <Property name="ReadOnly">true</Property>
            <Property name="MaxUserNameListLength">100</Property>
            <Property name="ConnectionURL">ldap://host</Property>
            <Property name="ConnectionName">ommitted</Property>
            <Property name="ConnectionPassword">xxxxxx</Property>
            <Property name="passwordHashMethod">PLAIN_TEXT</Property>
            <Property name="UserSearchBase">searchbase</Property>
            <Property name="UserNameListFilter">(objectClass=user)</Property>
            <Property name="UserNameAttribute">sAMAccountName</Property>
            <Property name="ReadLDAPGroups">true</Property>
            <Property name="GroupSearchBase">groupbase</Property>
            <Property name="GroupNameListFilter">(objectClass=group)</Property>
            <Property name="GroupNameAttribute">sAMAccountName</Property>
            <Property name="MembershipAttribute">memberOf</Property>
            <Property name="UserRolesCacheEnabled">false</Property>
            <Property name="ReplaceEscapeCharactersAtUserLogin">true</Property>
            <Property name="maxFailedLoginAttempt">0</Property> 
        </UserStoreManager>
```

I've removed specific connection details and UserSearchBase and GroupSearchBase.  IS starts up successfully, and I can see users and roles listed.

I'm encountering the following issues:

- The Identity server does not correctly map assigned roles to users.  Even though my AD uses the 'memberOf' attribute to define group membership, Identity server does not have any assigned to a particular user
- I am not able to log in to the Identity server admin UI with a user from my LDAP store.  When I configure Realm/Configuration in the following way:

  admin
                      
                           AD_user_name
                           admin
                      
                  everyone 
                  jdbc/WSO2CarbonDB
                  org.wso2.carbon.user.core.config.multitenancy.CommonLDAPRealmConfigBuilder
              
              org.wso2.carbon.user.core.config.multitenancy.CommonLDAPRealmConfigBuilder</Property-->

Does anyone have any suggestion for integrating with a readonly LDAP store that is ACtive directory?

**Update**
Working with WSO2 support, I would advise everyone to wait until IS 4.1.1 before attempting this particular use case.  Older versions of the product simply do not work very well.  I will update as I know more.

Comment: I am having the same problem. You have any luck yet?

Comment: Same issue here. Trying to get the WSO2 IS up with AD as a backend, none of the config combinations seem to work with read-only access. Please update if you were able to make any progress on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update:**

I can confirm that the WSO2 IS 4.1.1 resolves the issue and this works as expected.  I've come to the conclusion the product 4.1.0 flat out doesn't work.

The dev team has fixed the issues in those features and it's in the latest release.

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about Active Directory, but we were facing a similar problem on OpenLDAP, we could not list the roles of a user, the reason was, our LDAP was relating a user to a group by only using it's UID, for example, on the role the attribute memberUid was:

```
memberUid = alandaniel
```

but the way WSO2 org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager
expects is:

```
memberUid = uid=alandaniel,ou=x,dc=y,dc=z
```

so i had to customize the user.core plugin.
Instead of creating the query:

```
(&(objectClass=posixGroup)(memberUid=uid=alandaniel,ou=x,dc=y,dc=z))
```

it will now use

```
(&(objectClass=posixGroup)(memberUid=alandaniel))
```

So if you really need to customize it, extend ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager and customize the method getExternalRoleListOfUser(..)

*The versions used were WSO2 IS 4.1.0 and WSO2 ESB 4.6.0.

Comment: Is this still a problem with WSO2 IS 5.0.0?

Answer (score 0):

I have used the attached configuration in a recent customer engagement
Can you try with this, connecting with a user which has read access to AD ?

Also, newest version of IS now supports multiple user stores. If you want a single active store, make sure to comment the default one. Otherwise, you need to add a domain name per user store (here ad-domain).

User stores setup is described here: 
http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/IS400/Configuring+User+Stores

Hope this helps,
Isabelle.

```
<UserStoreManager class="org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ActiveDirectoryUserStoreManager">
<Property name="DomainName">ad-domain</Property>
<Property name="defaultRealmName">My-Realm</Property>
<Property name="kdcEnabled">false</Property>
<Property name="ConnectionURL">ldap://myserver:389</Property>
<Property name="ConnectionName">CN=yyyy,ou=xxxxx</Property>
<Property name="ConnectionPassword">xxxxxxx</Property>
<Property name="passwordHashMethod">PLAIN_TEXT</Property>
<Property name="UserSearchBase">ou=xxxx,...</Property>
<Property name="UserEntryObjectClass">user</Property>
<Property name="UserNameAttribute">sAMAccountName</Property>
<Property name="isADLDSRole">false</Property>
<Property name="userAccountControl">512</Property>
<Property name="UserNameListFilter">(objectClass=user)</Property>
<Property name="UserNameSearchFilter">(&amp;(objectClass=user)(cn=?))</Property>
<Property name="UsernameJavaRegEx">[a-zA-Z0-9._-|//]{3,30}$</Property>
<Property name="UsernameJavaScriptRegEx">^[\\S]{3,30}$</Property>
<Property name="PasswordJavaScriptRegEx">^[\\S]{5,30}$</Property>
<Property name="RolenameJavaScriptRegEx">^[\\S]{3,30}$</Property>
<Property name="RolenameJavaRegEx">[a-zA-Z0-9._-|//]{3,30}$</Property>
<Property name="ReadLDAPGroups">true</Property>
<Property name="WriteLDAPGroups">false</Property>
<Property name="EmptyRolesAllowed">true</Property>
<Property name="GroupSearchBase">ou=xxxxx</Property>
<Property name="GroupEntryObjectClass">group</Property>
<Property name="GroupNameAttribute">cn</Property>
<Property name="MembershipAttribute">member</Property>
<Property name="GroupNameListFilter">(objectcategory=group)</Property>
<Property name="GroupNameSearchFilter">(&amp;(objectClass=group)(cn=?))</Property>
<Property name="UserRolesCacheEnabled">true</Property>
<Property name="Referral">follow</Property>
<Property name="BackLinksEnabled">true</Property>
<Property name="maxFailedLoginAttempt">0</Property>
</UserStoreManager>
```

Comment: It looks like this setup is for a read/write user store - where Identity Server can add/edit users and roles, right?  What I specifically need is a read-only store...

Comment: Appreciate the response, but getting the same results.  I'm using the latest version of IS as well - 4.1.0

Answer (score 0):

Please refer following blog post by Suresh.

http://sureshatt.blogspot.com/2012/07/how-to-connect-wso2-api-manager-to.html

It has an example of using `ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager`.

I hope that helps.

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, I've worked through that blog post.  Unfortunately, I'm not able to get it working.

Comment: Appreciate the link to that blog - havent seen that before.  Unfortunately I'm getting the same results.