# wso2 identity server 4.10 readonly with custom UserManagerStore class

Tags: wso2

I have a class that extends AbstractUserStoreManager.

My problem is currently with the getRoleListOfUser() method. The list returned here shows up in the Unassigned Role list in the UI, rather than in the Assigned Role list. i.e. the method appears to be behaving like it is returning all possible roles, rather than the ones assigned to the user.

Is there an internal property I need to set with this role list? Is this a known bug?

```
    @Override
public String[] getRoleListOfUser(String userName)
        throws UserStoreException {

    // check whether roles exist in cache
    try {
        String[] names = getRoleListOfUserFromCache(this.tenantId, userName);
        if (names != null) {
            return names;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // if not exist in cache, continue
    }

    List<String> roles = new ArrayList<String>();

    // **code removed ** - but, roles is populated by a web service.

    String [] roleList = (String[]) roles.toArray(new String[roles.size()]);

    addToUserRolesCache(this.tenantId, userName, roleList);

            // TODO: make roleList apply to assigned roles, rather than unassigned roles!

    return roleList;
}
```

My implementation is unlike the existing examples, because I am using web service calls instead of querying directly against a user store with jdbc.

However, this appears similar to this issue: [ldap-user-store-not-working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15392148/wso2-identity-server-ldap-user-store-not-working) 
, except I am using my own class instead of LDAP.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

4.1.1 release associates roles with users correctly in AD and LDAP. This version is not out yet, maybe another three weeks. But the alpha release I am experimenting with has many improvements regarding role and domain association.